# Rows with the same primary key is updated simultaneously

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have session where after user login, they can book through the form and can update. However, the rows with the foreign key (user_id) in table **Tempahan** is updated simultaneously.

[image]

for example, if I want to click update for No4, it was updated BUT other rows is also changed.

**Table structure for table `user`** :
PK: user_id

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `user_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `user_password` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Table structure for table `tempahan`** : PK tempahan_id, FK user_id

```
CREATE TABLE `tempahan` (
  `tempahan_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `noPhone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `alamat` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `daerah` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `negeri` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `poskod` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `tajuk` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `anjuran` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `tarikh` date NOT NULL,
  `masa` time NOT NULL,
  `aturcara` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `user_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

below is the process of update. actually I use PDO but I removed it for awhile and use the mysqli statement.

```
<?php
    
        include("conn.php");
    
       session_start();
    
            $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
    
            $noPhone = $_POST["noPhone"];
            $alamat = $_POST["alamat"];
            $daerah = $_POST["daerah"];
            $negeri = $_POST["negeri"];
            $poskod = $_POST["poskod"];
            $tajuk = $_POST["tajuk"];
            $anjuran = $_POST["anjuran"];
            $tarikh = $_POST["tarikh"];
            $masa = $_POST["masa"];  
            
    
             $sql = "UPDATE TEMPAHAN SET noPhone = '$noPhone', alamat = '$alamat', 
            daerah = '$daerah', negeri = '$negeri', poskod = '$poskod', tajuk = '$tajuk', anjuran = '$anjuran'
            , tarikh = '$tarikh', masa = '$masa' where user_id = '$user_id'";
    
            $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        
    
            if($query)
                echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\"content=\"2;URL=senaraiTempahan.php\" />";
            else
                echo "Update failed";   
        
        
        
    ?>
```

Comment: You need to add full table definitions so we can see how the FK's are supposed to behave..

Comment: The query will update all rows with the same user ID. Are you trying to update a specific row in Tempahan? If so, then just use the primary key of that row in your WHERE clause (i.e. the tempahan_id)

Comment: @ADyson I think that's the problem. so in WHERE clause, like where tempahan_id= '$tempahan_id'"; ? Is that possible? I dont know, tempahan_id is auto increment, and the user_id is phone number.

Comment: @P.Salmon done edit.

Comment: Well presumably when you loaded the form to edit the row, you knew which row it was and what the ID of it was, so you can just submit that row ID back to PHP with the rest of the form, so that php can use it in the query.

Comment: @ADyson. got it! thank  you.

Comment: "PK: user_id" -- No, that's not true. The table definition does not define `user_id` as a primary key.

Comment: `tempahan_id is auto increment`...not according to your create table statement. Nor have you actually defined any primary or foreign keys anywhere.